# "Verify" API - logs and settings

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

We're implementing phone verification using the TWILIO "Verify" API and have a few questions:
1. Where may I see logs for the SMSs, with their status and all, same like I see for TWILIO Programmable SMS.
2. Where may I edit the 'from' name and the SMS text? couldn't find it anywhere.

thanks,
Eran

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can find the logs for the SMS's under https://www.twilio.com/console/verify/services/{your-service-SID}/logs.

[image]

To edit the SMS text, you must have `custom_message`, which can be passed in as an optional parameter to the `Create` method, enabled by the Verify team. To edit the `from`, you can edit the optional parameter `channel_configuration` also where you pass in the required `to` and `channel` parameters to the `Create` method, as mentioned in [these Verify "Start New Verification" docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#start-new-verification).